# Validation on radio button : javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have one registration form and want to add validation on gender section radio buttons.
My form is like

```
<form name="formreg" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
     <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" /> Male<br />
      <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" /> Female<br />
      <input value="Submit" onclick="return inputval()" type="submit" />
    </form>
```

I use below script but not working properly ..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function inputval(){
        if(document.getElementById("gender").checked=="false")
        {
            alert("Select at least male or female.");
            return false;
        }   
    }
    </script>
```

unable to find problem.

Comment: Look in your javascript console and tell us the error message please

Comment: its not showing any error ... but also not working

Comment: There is no gender id in your radio buttons.

Comment: See the first answer: set an ID to the input tags because you're selecting the name for an ID, which is selecting nothing. Thus, no error.

Answer (score 2):

you re getting the element By Id, and 'gender' is your input's name, not the id. 
instead of

```
<input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" /> Male<br />
```

you should use

```
<input type="radio" value="male" id="gender" /> Male<br />
```

Comment: Please.. elaborate (: Tell the OP what he/she *should* be doing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this with jquery, use `:checked` pseudo class selector.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function inputval()
{
    if($("form[name='formreg'] input[type='radio']:checked").length != 1)
    {
        alert("Select at least male or female.");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `:checked`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function inputval(){
    if($(':checked').length < 0)
    {
        alert("Select at least male or female.");
        return false;
    }   
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You put jQuery down, so I'll use that.  `document.getElementById('checked')` does not exist.  Even if it did, it would only apply to one element.  You would have to iterate over each of the `[name=gender]` elements to see if any is checked.  jQuery makes this trivial:

```
$(".inputval").on('click', function (e) {
    if (!$("[name=gender]:checked").length) {
        alert('something something gender');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/s2YfU/

EDIT: non-jQuery solution is also pretty trivial since `querySelectorAll('[name=gender]:checked')` works too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of validation.By default check one radio button

```
<form name="formreg" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
     <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" checked="true" /> Male<br />
      <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" /> Female<br />
      <input value="Submit" onclick="return inputval()" type="submit" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle could give you some ideas (without jquery). Note that I checked one of the buttons so I could show you that if one is checked, it will set anyChecked to true.

```
<form name="formreg" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" checked="checked"/>Male
    <br />
    <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" />Female
    <br />
    <input value="Submit" onclick="return inputval()" type="submit" />
</form>
<div id="output"></div>

var output = document.getElementById("output");
var genderInputs = document.getElementsByName("gender");
var anyChecked = false;

for (var j = 0; j < genderInputs.length; j++) {
    if (genderInputs[j].checked === true) {
        anyChecked = true;
        break;
    }
}

output.textContent = "any checked: " + anyChecked;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F8XGU/1/